# Assuming manga identification is on-topic, is this community okay being referred as an alternative resource on Anime & Manga SE?

Tags: discussion, story-identification

I stumbled upon [Educational manga about a mad scientist](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/9068/educational-manga-about-a-mad-scientist) which is a manga identification request on this site and from the look of it, I think it's allowed on this site (upvoted and not closed).

I found [What do we think about story identification?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-do-we-think-about-story-identification) and [Are comic identifications on topic?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/845/are-comic-identifications-on-topic?noredirect=1&lq=1) which seems to conclude that yes, identification request is on-topic.

**Anime & Manga Stack Exchange** is maintaining a meta post [What identification requests are acceptable here? Otherwise, where else can I possibly get helped with it?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4189) in which it provides alternative sites such as SE sister sites, or even external sites.

Considering that this site also looks like a suitable alternative site... now, before opening a possibility of flood gate of low-quality manga ID questions that have plagued Anime.SE:

1. Is this site open for being mentioned as an alternative site on a **comment**?
2. If yes, is this site also open to be **listed on the said meta post**?

(Of course, we'll try our best to provide recommended guidance before suggesting them to post on this site)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [golden rule of migration is "Don't Migrate Crap"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/348200). Story identification questions on this site must be as detailed as possible, with a few suggestions outlined in [Guidelines for good story-id questions?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/778/guidelines-for-good-story-id-questions); the [tag info page](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) is also always a good place to look.

I'm a bit of a regular in the Anime&Manga chat room, and from what I see, there aren't too many ID questions being asked on A&M anymore. Most of them are closed fast, and the crappier ones are closed and deleted even faster.

My point? I don't think we'll get an influx of bad questions because A&M community has a good sense of quality. I think we could use a bit of manga-related questions here, for an extra bit of diversity. I don't think this is a great venue *for the askers*: if we had many people able to answer such questions, I imagine we'd have more manga questions by now, but then I may be wrong, and maybe we'll get more users from A&M hanging out around here.

All things considered, I think it's perfectly fine to redirect askers here or migrate existing questions that pass the golden rule check.

Comment: Quoting the golden rule is only helpful if everyone can agree on what defines the subjective measure of "crap"ness. Judging from the comments of A&M regulars that I've seen, I'm not sure they and we have the same idea of what makes a "crap" ID question. This answer might be improved by linking to Lit's documentation on ID questions, e.g. meta and tag wiki.

Comment: Thanks, looks like there's no issue with it; I'll add this site to the Anime.SE meta post. Feel free to improve it if it lacks something!