# Can I re-ask a question from SF here?

Tags: discussion

I asked [a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186871/post-modernist-fantasy-with-nested-stories-structure) on SF about a piece of postmodern metafiction with a fantastic theme.  Some commenters questioned if it was a fit there, but ultimately it was accepted, but did not get much attention.

Could I re-ask it here?  My understanding is that cross-posting on SE is discouraged or forbidden.  How different would it need to be to not violate the spirit of this rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I can do. If you want it *migrated* here, rather than *reposted* here, I can throw a flag up on that question asking them to move it here. It's hardly a bad question, and it would be nice to have more examples of good story-ID questions on site.

I'm suggesting this because, for the reasons below, I'm not sure this is a good question to cross-post. Let me know if that works for you!

---

Cross-posting is, in my experience, generally okay if a question is:

- acceptable on multiple sites,
- the question is of very high quality,
- you're asking on one site at a time,
- the other site didn't give you the kinds of answers you wanted,
- the other site is a *worse* fit for the kind of question you're asking,
- bonus points if the question is likely to elicit different answers from the two communities.

The question you're asking about, in my eyes, is:

- [Acceptable here.](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-do-we-think-about-story-identification)
- Has a potential issue with quality. It's not that it's a poorly-asked question, and as far as story-ID questions go this is a key example of a good one. But by site consensus, for the reasons described in the prior link, story ID questions are not regarded as the prime example of a high quality question here.

  > Identification questions are like... The cabbage, radishes and shredded carrots that some sushi shops put on the platter before stacking up the meat & rice. They make the plate look nice and full, and they're something to chew on once you've eaten all the meat...
- You asked on that site, didn't get the answer you were looking for, so asking on here is, in my mind, okay by this point.
- Didn't get an answer on it, moot point.
- SF&F is... just about as good a fit for this question as Literature would be, honestly. So by this point it's kind of iffy, too.
- It's an ID question, so the answer is the same regardless of where it's posted.

Answer (score 3):

SFF moderator here - I'll be happy to **migrate the question** for you if you'd like it on Lit instead.

Alternatively, you can **delete it on SFF and re-post it here**. But then you'd lose the votes on it.

There's probably no point in leaving the same question open on *both* sites, because there's no way the two could answer it differently - the answer will be the same no matter where. See [Zyerah's answer](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1030/17).